# Pine Script Strategy Enter position when ta.cross and barcolor

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to enter a short position when the bar color is not orange and the ta.cross(high, upper3) ((upper3 is a Bollinger Band)). There should be NO entry when the bar color is orange.

```
//Kerzenfarben wenn High & Low auf äußeren BB

colourForBar = if (close > upper2_oben[1])
color.orange
else
  na

barcolor(color=colourForBar)

colourForBar2 = if (close < lower2_unten[1])
color.orange
else
  na
barcolor(color=colourForBar2)

//short Einstieg

if barcolor(colourForBar ? color.orange : na) and ta.cross(high, upper3)

strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the bar color to orange with this condition: `(close > upper2_oben[1])`. You can use the `not` operator to figure out if the bar color is **not** orange.

The potential problem is that, you have two `bacolor` function calls to set the barcolor. So, you need to figure out which one you want to use in your conditonal check.

```
is_not_orange = not (close > upper2_oben[1])
entry_cond = is_not_orange and ta.cross(high, upper3)

if (entry_cond)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

**Note:** It could be some formatting issue but your code does not respect the indentation rules. Make sure you follow the [rules](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Line_wrapping.html) if you don't already.